# '|' or operation in conditional mutating

Tags: r, dplyr

I could not figure it out why `|` logical operator doesn't worked.

```
  set.seed(123)
   add <- sample(rep(letters[1:4],times=4))
   value = c(rep(runif(4),times=4))
   id <- rep(c("Good","Bad","ugly","dirty"),each=4)

   df <- data.frame(add,value,id=sample(id))


     add      value    id
1    a    0.24608773 dirty
2    d    0.04205953  ugly
3    b    0.32792072  ugly
4    c    0.95450365 dirty
5    a    0.24608773   Bad
6    a    0.04205953  ugly
7    b    0.32792072   Bad
8    a    0.95450365  ugly
9    d    0.24608773  Good
10   d    0.04205953  Good
11   b    0.32792072 dirty
12   c    0.95450365   Bad
13   d    0.24608773 dirty
14   b    0.04205953  Good
15   c    0.32792072  Good
16   c    0.95450365   Bad
```

I try to add new column `label` with `|`,

```
df_clas <- df%>%
      mutate(label=ifelse(id=='dirty|ugly'&value<0.9,'Animal',''))
```

I am getting label column empty.

I also tried

```
 mutate(label=ifelse(id=='dirty'|'ugly'&value<0.9,'Animal',''))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    operations are possible only
>   for numeric, logical or complex types

But When I tried,

```
mutate(label=ifelse(id=='dirty'|id=='ugly'&value<0.9,'Animal',''))
```

it works but I want to use `'id'` only once in the beginning of the conditions. How can I do that ?

Comment: If you want to match one of multiple values, use `id %in% c('dirty','ugly')`

Comment: @MrFlick I am sorry I could not catch it!